# Firebase Authentication does not insert new values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I recently updated to the newest version of Xcode and I've got a lot of problems since then. I've a "Sign up" form where user can create a new account on the app but somehow it does not insert new values into the Authentication.

I commented out my code and just tried to run the normal create user function so my code looks like this right now:

```
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: txtfield_email.text!, password: txtfield_password.text!) { (adr, err) in
        if let err = err{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }else{
            print("Succeded creating a new user!")
        }
    }
```

So when I run the app it will go into the else and print out: "Succeded creating a new user!" but when I login to my Firebase account and check if any new values is added to the authentication the answer is no. Nothing is there.

I've updated all my pods including the Firebase and still does not work.

What could of happen? Why doesn't it run like normal?

Just to mention: I'm currently running it on the simulator (Not my own device). But like I said, nothing new is getting implemented in Authentication. (Everything worked perfectly fine before, but not after I updated...?)

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling on this for hours and hours. But once I posted this thread I found my solution.

If you find this error yourself the solution is.

Go to your console in Firebase and download the latest version of:

> GoogleService-info.plist

And replace your current one with the latest.